# ListView().toList .map - add separate widget (not mapped) inside ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an app which gets data from Firestore & maps it into a ListView - I'd like to have a custom `ElevatedButton()` inside the list View *(as a last item)*

I've tried wrapping my ListView inside an other ListView & adding the `button` there but it makes two different scroll ListView which is not the behavior I want

I'd like my button to be inside **this ListView** as a last item of the list - if possible

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['num']),
              subtitle: Text(data['num']),
            );
          }).toList(),
// ElevatedButton() ideally somewhere here
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) to combine the data and the button into a single list:

```
ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: [
        ...snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(data['num']),
            subtitle: Text(data['num']),
          );
        }).toList(),
        ElevatedButton()
      ],
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put these into a Column:

```
return Column(children: [ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['num']),
              subtitle: Text(data['num']),
            );
          }).toList(),
// ElevatedButton() ideally somewhere here]);
```

Comment: If you put it inside a `Column`, the button won't scroll with the `List`. OP wants to put the button at the end of the `List`

Comment: Right, then it won't work. Although I don't suggest to put button at the end of the list. It can be annoying for the user to scroll all the way down every time he wanna click the button.

Comment: That completely depends on the whole UX and what you wan't to accomplish with the UI. Often it would be bad UX to put it at the bottom after scroll yes, but that is a bit of topic for this question.

Comment: thks for your feedback @stacktrace2234 the `button` was just to simplify my question don't worry I won't have one inside the `ListView`